# JavaScript parameter value becomes undefined when passed through prototype chain

Tags: javascript, inheritance, parameters, prototype, undefined

I've established prototypal inheritance between **Parent** and **Child** with all parameters coming from an XMLHttpRequest of a JSON file. I've confirmed the JSON file is built correctly through typeof statements on each parameter before it is passed to the **Child constructor**.

For some reason, the type of **stringArray** changes from **object** to **undefined** when it reaches **Child.prototype.setText** and throws a **TypeError** when moving to the inherited **Parent.prototype.joinStringArray**.

EDIT: I've included the current formatting of the JSON data along with expected i/o;

JSON File Input:

```
{ 
  "products":[
    {"name":"Product 1","materials":["mat1","mat2"],"gloss":false},
    {"name":"Product 2","materials":["mat1"],"gloss":true},
    {"name":"Product 3","materials":["mat1","mat2","mat3"],"gloss":true},
    {"name":"Product 4","materials":["mat1"],"gloss":false}
  ]
}
```

HTML/JavaScript Process:

```
<main id="screen">
</main>
<script>
  // XMLHttpRequest() receives data in "var catalog"
  var product = new Child(catalog.products[0].name, catalog.products[0].materials, catalog.products[0].gloss);
  // DOM Insertion
  var productName = document.createElement("H2");
  productName.innerHTML = product.name;
  document.getElementById("screen").appendChild(productName);
  var productDesc = document.createElement("P");
  productDesc.innerHTML = product.text;
  document.getElementById("screen").appendChild(productDesc);
</script>
```

JavaScript Objects:

```
/* PARENT */
function Parent(name, stringArray) {
  this.name        = name;
  this.stringArray = stringArray;
  this.text        = this.setText(stringArray);
}
Parent.prototype.setText = function(stringArray) {
  // Generate a paragraph
  return this.name + ": made from " + this.joinStringArray(stringArray) + "."; 

}    
Parent.prototype.joinStringArray = function(stringArray) {
  var stringList = stringArray[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    stringList += (i == (stringArray.length - 1) ? " and " : ", ") + stringArray[i];
  }
  return stringList.toLowerCase();
}

/* CHILD */
function Child(name, stringArray, boolean) {
  Parent.call(this, name, stringArray);
  this.boolean = boolean;
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Child.prototype.setText = function(stringArray) {
  // Generate a paragraph
  return this.name + ": this " + (this.boolean ? "TRUE variant" : "FALSE variant") 
                   + " is made from " + this.joinStringArray(stringArray) + ".";
}
```

Expected Output:

```
<main id="screen">
  <h2>Product 1</h2>
  <p>Product 1: this FALSE variant is made from mat1 and mat2.</p>
</main>
```

Actual Output: **TypeError: stringArray is undefined**

Comment: Can you show us how you use these classes? What are your expected results, versus your actual results? Can you give a simple example of your inputs, as well?

Comment: Here's a plunker of your code: https://plnkr.co/edit/KIUsSm7NQt9SzRofF3yB?p=preview

Comment: @JoelCDoyle - Is that what you're looking for? (edited op)

Comment: Great, now what is the actual output? What is the error? As far as I can tell, in my plunker it's working fine.

Comment: I already included the error at the beginning of the OP, but I've copied the exact console error below.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. See the plunker. Other than needing to place `this.boolean = boolean` before `Parent.call(this, name, stringArray);` your code works fine.

Comment: I'll go back through my code to check for syntax errors, as I might have corrected the mistake when converting variable names over for readability. Also, would testing the XHR process on a local JSON file through Firefox cause any problems? I know that most browsers require external files to be available on a web server, but I've been using local files during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Credit goes to JoelCDoyle in the comments for reminding me that statement order matters!)

This inheritance setup is part of a much larger object tree that has several other variables being called in the **Parent constructor**. I tried pulling out only the code responsible for the system I was having trouble with, but it appears that inadvertently solved my problem.

The relevant part of my code is as follows but with the **vendor parameter** added to the mix:

```
/* PARENT */
function Parent(vendor, name, stringArray) {
  // PROPERTIES
}
// METHODS

}    
/* CHILD */
function Child(name, stringArray, boolean) {
  Parent.call(this, name, stringArray, this.vendor);
  this.vendor = "SomeVendor";      
  this.boolean = boolean;
}
```

Each **Child object** has a set **vendor** that is passed to the **Parent** (along with several other variables I haven't included). There's enough distance between these lines of code that I failed to notice the parameter order was different.

So, when JoelCDoyle mentioned my **Child properties** needed to be moved above the **Parent call**, I copypasta'd them above it. That's when I noticed the issue and corrected it:

```
/* PARENT */
function Parent(vendor, name, stringArray) {
  // PROPERTIES
}
// METHODS

}    
/* CHILD */
function Child(name, stringArray, boolean) {
  this.vendor = "SomeVendor";      
  this.boolean = boolean;
  Parent.call(this, this.vendor, name, stringArray);  
}
```

My **stringArray** values were always correct, but they were being handed to the wrong parameter. By fixing both my parameter and statement orders, my code now works exactly as expected :D